# Pass a Python function to the Python function, but which is C/C++ extension

Tags: python, c++

For ex i have some Python function

```
def return_value(n):
    return 3.14 * n
```

and C code for extension

```
#include <Python.h>

double f(double x) {
    if (x > 0) 
        return x * x;
    return x + x;
}

static PyObject* f_cpp(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    
    PyObject* f_py;  // from args
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &f_py)) { // where func is return_value
        return NULL;
    }
    double x = f_py(5); // or the same return_value(5) and ERROR here;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(f(x));
} 
....
```

and i want to pass return_value to f_cpp in Python code like this
`print(f_cpp(return_value))`, but i dont know how to do that. I read docs, where I found the optinons "O", but it didnt help me.

Comment: You are looking for the callable object protocol. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#object-calling-api

Comment: I did it, thanks.
`x = PyObject_CallFunction(f_py, "i", 5); `
`double y = PyFloat_AsDouble(x);`
`return PyFloat_FromDouble(y);`